# Condição automática para uma variável.

Tags: python

Criei um personagem para um jogo usando uma classe e dentro dessa classe eu coloquei o atributo life = 10. Durante o percurso desse personagem, ele recebe alguns danos provenientes de ataques de inimigos danos os quais eu subtario do life. Quando esse life chegar a 0 esse personagem morre.

Durante todo o meu código, quando o personagem é atacado eu tenho que criar uma condição if **(if life <= 0: print("VOcê morreu). else: (...)**

Há algum jeito de eu atribuir essa condição apenas uma vez para esse atributo? Só queria isso para poder diminuir e organizar o meu código, mas toda vez que o personagem é atacado eu tenho que criar a condição novamente.

Abraços e espero que entendam!!

Answer (score 2):

Há sim,  você tem justamente que estar usando classes. Você praticamente não colocou nenhum código, mas se estiver ok, você acessa o life no código usando `self.life` (ou se for fora dos métodos da própria classe, `nome_do_objeto.life`)

Bom, o que acontece em Python é que há como definir que alguns atributos sejam `properties`: em vez de simplesmente armazenar o valor, o Python chama automaticamente um método cada vez que você quiser ler ou escrever um valor no atributo.

O uso moderno mais normal do property é como um decorador do método de *ler* valor que você quer para o atributo. Depois o próprio método pode ser usado como um decorador para o método de escrever no atributo.  Mas essa forma fica mais confusa de entender a princípio - para fins didáticos, eu vou demonstrar primeiro a forma antiga de usar o property: você passa  a função "getter" e a "setter" como parâmetros, e ele devolve o objeto que será usado como "atributo inteligente".

```
class Jogador:  # em geral
    def __init__(self, ...):
         self.life = 10
         ...

    def set_life(self, value):
        self._life = value
        if self._life <= 0:
             print("Você morreu") 
             # Mas melhor que usar o print, é fazer raise em 
             # uma exceção customizada - veja abaixo
             ...

    def get_life(self):
        return self._life

    life = property(get_life, set_life)
```

Pronto  - pode fazer testes com essa classe - cada vez que alguém tentar colocar um valor igual a zero ou negativo em `life`, ele vai fazer o print. Perceba que ele ainda precisa guardar o valor real em algum lugar- por praxe usamos o nome do atributo com um "_" como prefixo: o self._life no caso funciona como um atributo normal de Python - mas todo o código que for escrito, deve usar o self.life - e aí o código das duas funçõezinhas acima é executado. (inclusive se você usar os operadores de atribuição aumentada, do tipo `self.life -= 1`)

O "property" é um construtor embutido no Python que retorna um objeto especial, que ao ser associado a um atributo dentro de uma classe ganha essas propriedades.  Quem quiser entender os detalhes de como isso funciona internamente deve procurar ler sobre o "descriptor protocol" do Python.

Então, tem mais duas coisas bacanas pra falar: a primeira é usar o property como é usado "modernamente", com a sintaxe de decoradores.

E a segunda é - veja que nesse código podemos fazer o print de que o "jogador" morreu, mas o jogo vai continuar funcionando normalmente  -  até achar um "if" que verifique a vida; 
O ideal é que quando o método detectar que a vida caiu abaixo de zero, você quer sair da rotina principal do jogo, e ir para uma tela de "fim de jogo" (ou o código que subtrai um "continue", etc...) - Para isso, fazemos uso do mecanismo de exceção do Python - o mesmo que normalmente é usado pela lignaugem quando há um erro. Nesse caso, fazemos um uso controlado dele - primeiro criando uma exceção específica para "GameOver", e em seguida, executando o código principal do jogo dentro de um bloco try/except .

Tudo junto, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
class GameOver(Exception):
    pass  
    # Isso mesmo - basta herdar de exception e não fazer mais nada
    # "GameOver" agora pode ser usado com o comando Except.

class Jogador:
    def __init__(self, ...):
         self.life = 10
         ...
    @property
    def life(self):
        return self._life

    @life.setter
    def life(self, value):
        self._life = value
        if self._life <= 0:
             raise GameOver

def principal():
   jogador = Jogador()
   while True:
       # aqui vai o código principal do seu jogo
       # quando o jogador morrer, a execeção vai fazer
       # o programa sair desse while, e cair dentro
       # do bloco "except GameOver" abaixo. 

def controle():
   continua = "s"
   while continua == "s":
       try:
           principal()
       except GameOver:
           print("Você morreu!")
           continua = input("Jogar de novo? (s/n) :")

controle()
```

Note que a mesmíssima estrutura funcionaria também para um jogo no modo gráfico usando o pygame, por exemplo.
Já outras bibliotecas gráficas, como pyglet, ou mesmo o tkinter, pygtk, e pyqt, funcionam num esquema diferente, com eventos e callbacks - nesses casos, o seu programa não teria um `while True` como o que está acima - a própria biblioteca gráfica tem um laço principal dela, onde ela checa eventos.  E aí, em vez de usar exceções para controlar o fluxo do programa, você usa os mecanismos de "eventos" - cada biblioteca dessas vai ter um sistema de eventos. O "property" funciona da mesma forma, mas em vez do "Raise", você adiciona um evento de "GameOver" - que deve ser tratado apropriadamente.